# CentOS VPS server showing wrong HDD space

Tags: vps

The VPS server HDD has total size of 12G and 6.7G of it's used but then in **Avail** column it shows only 944M available while it should be 5.3G.

Do you have any idea what is causing this and how can I fix it

```
root@server# df -h
Filesystem                        Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/simfs                        12G   6.7G 944M  88%  /
none                              512M  4.0K 512M   1%  /dev
```

Comment: Plase don't post images of *text*.  Just put it here in the question.

Comment: There, I fixed it.

Comment: Thank you larks and I'm sorry for being a noob around here, do you know how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell `/dev/simfs/` suggests that you are using an OpenVZ VPS node on a hosting provider.  In this case, according to [this](http://lowendtalk.com/discussion/3162/simfs-crippled), a lack of space on the physical node hosting your virtual instance can result in this situation.  While your virtual instance has been allocated up to 12G of space, the physical node has less than that available.

Ultimately, this seems like a question best directed to your hosting provider.

Comment: Thank you. I'll contact technical support then. Thought as if something was wrong on my side.